# firebase get some data using where

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is my firebase each group of documents added by different user I want to get the documents based in the userId filed I sored that filed in id variable and that is my code the condition is not working, it gets me all documents in glucose collection

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('glucose')
                .where('userId', isEqualTo: id)
                .snapshots(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                for (int index = 0;
                    index < snapshot.data.docs.length;
                    index++) {
                  DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                  chartData.add(ChartData.fromMap(documentSnapshot.data()));
                }
```

[image]

Comment: try confirming if the other documents have the same **userId** or different

Comment: it has different userId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query, let me know if it works :)

Also, in this case you will probably going to get `Map` so you can use `.map((e) => null).toList()` to get them in list and render them using `ListView` or `Column` or what ever suits you :)

```dart
 StreamBuilder(
            stream:
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('glucose').snapshots(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data.docs.map(
                    (singleDoc) {
                      if (snapshot.data.docs.contains(singleDoc['userID']))
                        return Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(
                              singleDoc['someFieldHere'],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                    },
                  ).toList(),
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
```

Comment: the doc id is not equivalents to the user id so this will not work

Comment: It will automatically check if there is an `docID` equal to `userID` or not. Secondly, if they aren't equal then why are you passing it? What's the use?

Comment: if u r free to help give me ur twitter account to explain the idea

Comment: I have updated the answer check this one out it doesn't work my social handles are at my profile you can reach me anytime :)

Comment: check your twitter please